# pysnmp addVarbinds to Notification CPU Value

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am specifically trying to send SNMP TRAP to Manager including a CPU Value (cpuValue), which i get from SNMPGET Function. Yet, i couldnt find a way how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is a snipe of my pysnmp script.

```
cpuValue = GetCPU(cpuMontype)


    if cpuValue == -1:
        printString = "Could not poll %s CPU value " %(cpuMontype)
        printString += "from device %s" %(name)
        print printString

    elif cpuValue > 1.0:



        mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder().loadModules('UCD-SNMP-MIB')

        mibNode, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('UCD-SNMP-MIB', 'laLoad' )

        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        sendNotification(SnmpEngine(snmpEngineId),
                        UsmUserData ('authOnlyUser', 'password', 'password',
                                authProtocol=ntforg.usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                                privProtocol=ntforg.usmAesCfb128Protocol),
                        UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 162)),
                        ContextData(),
                        'trap',
                        NotificationType(
                            ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.5')
                        ).**addVarBinds(ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteHotValue', 0))**
                        )
        )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

When sending SNMP notification you need to provide its type (which is a MIB object) so you pass it to NotificationType. Notification may be defined (in MIB) in a way that current values of other (related) MIB objects should be included. For example *mteTriggerFired* notification implies inclusion of specified MIB OBJECTS:

```
mteTriggerFired NOTIFICATION-TYPE
OBJECTS { mteHotTrigger,
          mteHotTargetName,
          mteHotContextName,
          mteHotOID,
          mteHotValue }
STATUS  current
::= { dismanEventMIBNotifications 1 }
```

In pysnmp, to provide concrete values for MIB objects implicitly included into notification, NotificationType accepts a dictionary mapping MIB objects to values:

```
...
NotificationType(
    ObjectIdentity('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteTriggerFired'),
    instanceIndex=(0,),
    objects={('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteHotTrigger'): 'trigger',
             ('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteHotTargetName'): 'target',
             ('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteHotContextName'): 'context',
             ('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteHotOID'): '1.3.6.1.1.1',
             ('DISMAN-EVENT-MIB', 'mteHotValue'): 1234}
)
```

That should produce the following TRAP PDU:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 0
1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.0.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.1.0 = trigger
1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.2.0 = target
1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.3.0 = context
1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.4.0 = 1.3.6.1.1.1
1.3.6.1.2.1.88.2.1.5.0 = 1234
```

Example [script](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/evaluating-notification-type.html#snmpv2c-trap-via-notification-type) that should run out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your example on how to produce TRAP PDU. 
Regarding to my requirments to send lets say CPU Value within TRAP PDU i used v2c.TrapPDU( ) and it works fine for me.

Snipe :

```
    trapPDU =  v2c.TrapPDU()
    v2c.apiTrapPDU.setDefaults(trapPDU)

    v2c.apiTrapPDU.setVarBinds(
    trapPDU, [
    # sysUpTime
    ( v2c.ObjectIdentifier('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0'), v2c.TimeTicks(123) ),
    # snmpTrapPDU
    ( (1,3,6,1,6,3,1,1,4,1,0),   
    v2c.ObjectIdentifier((1,3,6,1,2,1,88,2,0,1))),
    ( (1,3,6,1,2,1,88,2,1,5,0), v2c.Integer32(cpuValue))
```